# layout-align="space-around " does not work in chrome and safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, angular-material

I am doing a side menu, using Angular material. The menu has 5 icons, four on top and then a span that flexes and then an icon at the bottom. I do it by using `layout-align="space-around start"` on a `layout="column"`. It should look like the first picture, like it does in Firefox, but it does not look like this in Chrome and Firefox, as shown in the second picture.

Firefox: [image: Firefox] Chrome and Safari: [image: Chrome]

Does someone know why it does this in Chrome and Safari? I think that the `space-around` does not work.. Why? How can I make it look like in Firefox in the rest of the browsers, without major hacking... Thanks!

And yes, I should probably tell you that this is the non-expanded version of the menu, you may see that there is more in the html. The menu expands on hover and that's made with a function and some css but that's irrelevant for this bug. The icons are spaced the same way if I remove all of the other functions.

You see my html below:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left darkgrey-bkgr {{mainVC.menuOpen}}" md-is-locked-open="true" md-disable-backdrop ng-mouseover="mainVC.openMenu()" ng-mouseleave="mainVC.closeMenu()">
  <div class="innerDiv" layout="column">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools" flex="100">
        <md-icon  md-svg-src="images/logo.svg">
        </md-icon>
        <p class="no-margin-tb margin-lx">text</p>
        <span flex></span>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="column" layout-align="space-around start" flex="100">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="DOC-bn"><i class="material-icons">map</i></md-button>
        <label for="DOC-bn">
          <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
            DOC
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="dashboard-bn"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></md-button>
        <label for="dashboard-bn">
          <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
            Dashboard
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="profile-bn"><i class="material-icons">account_box</i></md-button>
        <label for="profile-bn">
          <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
            Profile
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="settings-bn"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></md-button>
        <label for="settings-bn">
          <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
            Settings
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <span flex="30"></span>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="logout-bn"><i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i></md-button>
        <label for="logout-bn">
          <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
            Logout
          </p>
        </label>
        <p class="md-body-1 no-margin-tb margin-lx italic">
          Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: Did you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent container must use all the available space. In your code you are not using it.

```
  <div class="innerDiv" layout="column">
```

Plus most of the times this panel should not have a scroll-bar so better use `md-content` is that case. I strongly recommend not to use layout-align as its implementation changes on each browser. Try to use

`<span flex></span>`

for these kind of spacing.

Here is your full working code.

```
 <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left darkgrey-bkgr {{mainVC.menuOpen}}" md-is-locked-open="true" md-disable-backdrop ng-mouseover="mainVC.openMenu()" ng-mouseleave="mainVC.closeMenu()" flex>
```

```
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools" flex="100">
    <md-icon  md-svg-src="images/logo.svg">
    </md-icon>
    <p class="no-margin-tb margin-lx">text</p>
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-content layout="column" flex layout-align="space-around start" style='background-color:red'>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="DOC-bn"><i class="material-icons">map</i></md-button>
    <label for="DOC-bn">
      <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
        DOC
      </p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="dashboard-bn"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></md-button>
    <label for="dashboard-bn">
      <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
        Dashboard
      </p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="profile-bn"><i class="material-icons">account_box</i></md-button>
    <label for="profile-bn">
      <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
        Profile
      </p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="settings-bn"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></md-button>
    <label for="settings-bn">
      <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
        Settings
      </p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span flex="30"></span> // here use flex only and remove layout-align option if possible
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button white-text" id="logout-bn"><i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i></md-button>
    <label for="logout-bn">
      <p class="md-body-2 no-margin-tb">
        Logout
      </p>
    </label>
    <p class="md-body-1 no-margin-tb margin-lx italic">
      Text
    </p>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Here is a workgin link. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/qNEZZM

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/qNEZZM